# Is there any way to export as a SVG on Konva

Tags: konvajs, react-konva, konva, konvajs-reactjs

In my project I am using konvajs. Is there any way to export as a SVG image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found library to do that, which is quite new. I did some tests, and it seems to work well.

This library for Konva React version.

```
npm install react-konva-to-svg
```

**Links**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-konva-to-svg

Answer (score 2):

`Konva` doesn't have an API to export a stage into SVG.  The only way around is to make your own SVG-to-konva and konva-to-SVG converter.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an svg by using the canvas2svg package and tying it into the underlying canvas reference.

You can set your Layer's context equal to a c2s instance, rendering it, and resetting your Layer's ref to what it was previously, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70841507/react-konva-custom-context-canvas-for-use-with-canvas2svg).